# save .class name in a listview through sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

hi i am making a dictionary app and i want that when i open a word from a listview , then in the word page (word.class) (where the word meaning is explained), i want to add that word into a favorite.class activity in a listview shape and later on i can retrive that word from the listview.

i want to hit the favorite button in one java class and to save that word(string which is class name for that word) in anathor activity of favorite.class. the favorite button is actually is the menu item visible on the action bar. please explain me all the code and the way how can i do this..please give some code so to acomplish it.

```
public class Atherosclerosis extends Activity {

    // declare variables for the table of content and paragraph heading here//

    ScrollView scrollView;

     TextView sign_atherosclerosis;
     TextView sign_id;

     TextView def_id;
     TextView def_atherosclerosis;

     TextView riskfac_id;
     TextView riskfac_atherosclerosis;

     TextView pathophy_id;
     TextView pathophy_atherosclerosis;

     TextView Dx_id;
     TextView Dx_atherosclerosis;

     TextView Rx_id;
     TextView Rx_atherosclerosis;

     TextView prevent_id;
     TextView prevent_atherosclerosis;

     TextView compl_id;
     TextView compl_atherosclerosis;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.atherosclerosis);



        //here relate the variable for clickonlistener activity and direct scrolldown activity //

        final ScrollView scrollView=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollatherosclerosis);

        TextView sign_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Signandsymptomps_id);
        final TextView sign_atherosclerosis=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Signandsymptoms_atherosclerosis);


        TextView def_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.definition_id);
        final TextView def_atherosclerosis=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.definition_atherosclerosis);

        TextView riskfac_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.riskfactor_id);
        final TextView riskfac_atherosclerosis=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.riskfactor_atherosclerosis);

        TextView pathophy_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pathophysiology_id);
        final TextView pathophy_atherosclerosis=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pathophysiology_atherosclerosis);

        TextView Dx_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Diagnosis_id);
        final TextView Dx_atherosclerosis=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.diagnosis_atherosclerosis);

        TextView Rx_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.treatment_id);
        final TextView Rx_atherosclerosis=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.treatment_atherosclerosis);

        TextView prevent_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prevention_id);
        final TextView prevent_atherosclerosis=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prevention_atherosclerosis);

        TextView compl_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.complication_id);
        final TextView compl_atherosclerosis=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.complication_atherosclerosis);

        // this code is used for the action bar color change//
         ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#6B8E23")));
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 




// this is the code for jumping from the table of content to the paragraph//
            sign_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scrollView.post(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    new CountDownTimer(300, 20) {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int) (sign_atherosclerosis.getBottom()-millisUntilFinished));
                                        }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onFinish() {                 
                                       }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
            });

            def_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scrollView.post(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    new CountDownTimer(300, 20) {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int) (def_atherosclerosis.getBottom()-millisUntilFinished));
                                        }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onFinish() {                 
                                       }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
            });

            riskfac_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scrollView.post(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    new CountDownTimer(300, 20) {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int) (riskfac_atherosclerosis.getBottom()-millisUntilFinished));
                                        }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onFinish() {                 
                                       }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
            });

            pathophy_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scrollView.post(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    new CountDownTimer(300, 20) {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int) (pathophy_atherosclerosis.getBottom()-millisUntilFinished));
                                        }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onFinish() {                 
                                       }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
            });

            Dx_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scrollView.post(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    new CountDownTimer(300, 20) {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int) (Dx_atherosclerosis.getBottom()-millisUntilFinished));
                                        }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onFinish() {                 
                                       }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
            });

            Rx_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scrollView.post(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    new CountDownTimer(300, 20) {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int) (Rx_atherosclerosis.getBottom()-millisUntilFinished));
                                        }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onFinish() {                 
                                       }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
            });

            prevent_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scrollView.post(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    new CountDownTimer(300, 20) {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int) (prevent_atherosclerosis.getBottom()-millisUntilFinished));
                                        }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onFinish() {                 
                                       }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
            });

            compl_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scrollView.post(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    new CountDownTimer(300, 20) {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                            scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int) (compl_atherosclerosis.getBottom()-millisUntilFinished));
                                        }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onFinish() {                 
                                       }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
            });
    }

    // this is for the options selected from the menu button of mobile//
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.atherosclerosis, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // for starting activity from the option or menu//
      @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Take appropriate action for each action item click
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.id_search:
                Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(this,Search.class);     
                 startActivity(newActivity0);
                return true;
            case R.id.id_favorit:
                SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("bookmarks", MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putString("favorite", "com.kmcpesh.shortreviewofcardiology.Favorite");
                editor.commit();


               return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
}
```

this is my favorite.class activity

```
public class Favorite extends Activity {

    private TextView mEmptyText;
    private LinearLayout mBookmarkLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorite);

        mEmptyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_textview);
        mBookmarkLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bookmark_insert_point);

        getAllKeys();
    }
     private void getAllKeys()
        {
            SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("bookmarks", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Map<String,?> keys = sp.getAll();

            int count = 0;
            for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet())
            {
                String value = entry.getValue().toString();
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!value = "+value);
                String delimiter = ",";
                String[] values_array = value.split(delimiter);
                addBookmark(values_array);
                count++; //keep track of the number of bookmarks
            }

            //if there are no bookmarks, display a text view saying so.  Otherwise, make the text view go away
            if (count == 0)
            {
                mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEmptyText.setText(getString(R.string.no_bookmark));
            }
            else
                mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private void addBookmark(String[] values_array)
        {       
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.favorite, null);

            TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_text);


            text.setText(values_array[1]);

            // insert into main view
            mBookmarkLayout.addView(v, 0, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Just added a view");
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.favorite, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to do your own research into java. Try to figure this out yourself then ask a specific question here.

Comment: are you working with Database ?? and could you post some code ?

Comment: No I am not using database...I want it to be store through sharedpreferences

Comment: It sounds like you don't quite understand the basic workings of Android or Java yet.  It's good to jump in feet first and learn by doing, but your time might be better spent with a little more research first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences in Android is generally used to store key=value pairs, not lists such as the one you describe.  To store a value into SharedPreferences, you can do this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor ed = sp.edit();
ed.putString("myKey", "myValue");
```

And then to retrieve a string key from SharedPreferences, you would do this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String value = sp.getString("myKey", "");
```

You could have a comma-delimited list of favorite words stored in here, and just parse the list:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor ed = sp.edit();
ed.putString("favorites", "dog,cat,bird,fish");
```

And then to retrieve them:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String favorites = sp.getString("myKey", "");
String[] words = values.split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Then you have an array containing all of your favorite words.

```
[dog, cat, bird, fish]
```

Comment: where i ll point these save to Favorite.class so that i can see it later on?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  But I think what you want to do is, when your Favorite activity is launched, read the SharedPreferences you've written and present them in a menu to the user.